# Can only connect to uTorrent WebUI when on local network

Tags: port-forwarding, nat, utorrent

My port forwarding is all set up, I can connect to WebUI hosted from my laptop with my phone but only with my LAN IP when I'm on the same network. When I try to use the public one (WAN), I can't get it to work. Even turning off all my firewalls (Windows Firewall and the ones Linksys provides in their router config page) and turning off all my internet filters and VPN passthrough settings doesn't work. I don't know if it's a problem with my ISP or what.

Comment: Are you using your actual external IP when trying to access it remotely, i.e. `http://MyExternalIP:Port/gui`?

Comment: @happy_soil Yes

Answer (score -1):

With these settings, this should work... try it with a different port, for e.g. port 80. That should be openened by ISP. If works, you can choose a "normal" port.